# RegExp | Match patterns that may contain trailing text of any length

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string where a repeated same length main pattern (aa1111bbb2222ccccc) *may* or *may not* be followed by text (*) of *any length*, like so:

```
aa1111bbb2222ccccc********aa1111bbb2222ccccc****************
aa1111bbb2222cccccaa1111bbb2222ccccc****aa1111bbb2222ccccc
```

I would need to match substrings into patterns that start with the same length main pattern and includes trailing text (if any).

I'll be wrapping matching substring patterns like so (using above string):

```
<div class="substring-pattern">
<div class="title">aa1111bbb2222ccccc</div>
<div class="comment">********</div>
</div>
<div class="substring-pattern">
<div class="title">aa1111bbb2222ccccc</div>
<div class="comment">****************</div>
</div>
<div class="substring-pattern">
<div class="title">aa1111bbb2222ccccc</div>
<div class="comment"></div>
</div>
<div class="substring-pattern">
<div class="title">aa1111bbb2222ccccc</div>
<div class="comment">****</div>
</div>
<div class="substring-pattern">
<div class="title">aa1111bbb2222ccccc</div>
<div class="comment"></div>
</div>
```

Help appreciated. I'm stuck on the substring pattern matching script, disregard the html wrapping stuff.

Comment: I tried this so far with another pattern, but no luck: ./(([A-Z-]{1}\d{2}\\d{2}\\d{2}\\d{2}[A-Z-]{1})([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]{11}))(\s\S)/ , I'm learning in regex.

Comment: Thx for the downvotes. That is why newbies cannot learn form those who cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what lookaheads are for:

```
/(aa1111bbb2222ccccc)([\s\S]*?)(?=aa1111bbb2222ccccc|$)/g
```

[**Regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/hT5cI3/1); the pattern is held in the first capturing group, the remainder - in the second one. Using the lazy star prevents overcapturing.

---

As (almost always), there's an alternative approach, using `indexOf` to identify the positions of the substring in the string, then slicing the source accordingly:

```
var str    = 'aa1111bbb2222ccccc********aa1111bbb2222ccccc****************\naa1111bbb2222cccccaa1111bbb2222ccccc****aa1111bbb2222ccccc';
var marker = 'aa1111bbb2222ccccc';
var markerLen = marker.length; 

var matches = [];
var start = str.indexOf(marker);
var end;
while (start !== -1) {
  end = start + markerLen;
  start = str.indexOf(marker, end);
  matches.push({
     title: marker,
     comment: str.slice(end, start === -1 ? void 0 : start)
  });
}
console.log(matches);
```

[**Eval.in demo**](https://eval.in/424873).

Comment: Thx for your firendly help and best approach. Greatly appreciated. Yes, I was just reading about "lookaheads", should be promising.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
(aa1111bbb2222ccccc)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V9ZLpOSfgf4JirYL)